# Quotient group of normal subgroups is cyclic if quotient group of intersection is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $M$, $N$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$.

Prove that if $G/M\cap N$ is cyclic, then $G/M$ and $G/N$ are cyclic. Give a counter example to show that the converse is not always true.

I proved until now that if $G/M\cap N$ is abelian, then $G/M$ and $G/N$ are abelian, I don't know if that helps a lot but it's the only thing I could come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint for $\implies$:**

- Any quotient of a cyclic group is a cyclic group.
- [The third isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem).

**Hint for $\;\;\,\not\!\!\!\!\impliedby$:**

- There is a counterexample to the converse where $G$ has four elements (there are not very many such groups, so it should be easy to work out).

Answer (score 1):

There is a natural surjective map $G/(M \cap N) \to G/M$.  This means $G/M$ is a quotient of the group $G/(M \cap N)$.  Did you know that quotients of cyclic groups still cyclic?  If not, prove it yourself.  It's not too hard :)

Comment: cheers! how about the counter example? that's actually what gave me more troubles

Comment: Try something of the form $G = M \times N$.

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample, I think the following works: $$G=\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^2=[a,b]=1\rangle$$ Take $M=\langle a\rangle$ and $N=\langle b\rangle$.

Comment: :-D Very nice counterexample! +1